# CSS flexbox model and image width

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having some trouble with sizing an image inside a div with the `display` property set to `box` or `inline-box` (`inline-flex`).

CSS

```
.thumb {
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px;
    /* Firefox */
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    /* W3C */
    display: inline-flex;
    box-pack: center;
    box-align: center;
}

.thumb img {
    width: 280px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="image1.png" alt="Image 1" />
</div>
```

In Chrome the result is what I've expected, the image width is 280px, the height is proportional to the width and the image is centered horizontally and vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/AkwDk/.

In Firefox and Opera, however, the result differs in that the image width is ignored, while the height is 100%. I was able to fix the height problem, at least in FF, by adding `margin: auto` to the image, but the width problem remains: http://jsfiddle.net/AkwDk/1/.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, use Flexbox responsibly, do not use the old deprecated properties without also providing their modern counterparts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you have to understand about Firefox is that its implementation of the deprecated 2009 Flexbox draft is broken in many ways.  The good news is that Firefox is implementing the CR Flexbox draft *soon*.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/prHKc

```
.thumb {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #fafafa), color-stop(100%, #eaeaea));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fafafa, #eaeaea);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fafafa, #eaeaea);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fafafa, #eaeaea);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fafafa, #eaeaea);
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CACACA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.thumb img {
  max-width: 280px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```